# Scriptable DVD authoring solution for Linux?

Tags: linux, dvd, authoring

I am currently using [DVD Flick](http://www.dvdflick.net/) in Windows to author a DVD from a .vob video file in a manual process, i.e. setting up the project etc..

Now, I would like to

1. do the same in **Linux**, i.e. author a DVD from a .vob file. I dont need any fancy menus etc. just create the DVD structure for a video file, which just plays when inserting the DVD.
2. automate the creation of the DVD as much as possible, i.e. **scripting support** or **CLI**

If possible the solution should allow to create an ISO for easy duplication.

Does anybody know any software that supports this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**dvdauthor**](http://dvdauthor.sourceforge.net/) is an excellent command-line utility that can do what you want. There are also a number of GUI authoring tools, a lot of which are front-ends for dvdauthor:

- [QDVDAuthor](http://qdvdauthor.sourceforge.net)
- [DVD Styler](http://dvdstyler.sourceforge.net)
- [DeVeDe](http://www.rastersoft.com/programas/devede.html)
- [ManDVD](http://www.kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=83906)
- [tovid](http://tovid.wikia.com/wiki/Tovid_Wiki)

On Ubuntu, some of these are already included in the repository, so you can install them using *apt-get* or graphically through the  *Add/Remove..* menu.

A full list of front-ends to dvdauthor, as well tutorials on its use, are on the project site.

Answer (score 0):

This page offers a command-line solution:

http://movabletripe.com/archive/merging-avis-into-a-single-dvd-on-linux/

You could encapsulate those commands in a script, but you might have to include some options for things like aspect ratio.