# DVD authoring software that makes menus automatically (using filenames in menus)?

Tags: dvd-burning, authoring

I often grab handfuls of .mpg or .avi movies and burn them to playable DVDs.

I like having DVD menus, but I don't really need them to say anything beyond what's in the filename.

Right now I'm using DeVeDe, but I'm growing tired of creating and editing an entry for each file I add to the DVD.

Is there a (free, Windows or Linux) DVD authoring tool that will allow me to select a bunch of files and automatically create the ISO along with a default menu that simply uses the filenames?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DVD Flick](http://www.dvdflick.net/) is a free DVD authoring application that I use for this exact requirement. It comes with a bundle of built in menu designs to choose from.

The guide is [here](http://www.dvdflick.net/guide/index_en.html) on how to author and create a DVD with a menu from scratch.

**[Updated]**

Also, the [DVD Flick forums](http://dvdflick.net/forums/) (check out the sticky post under *Help and Support*) seems to have some resources on downloading and implementing custom menus. Maybe something there can give you exactly what you want.

Comment: This seems to work. The default menus are all two-page, strangely. It would be nice to just list all titles on a single menu page.

Comment: Yah, the 2-page menus do kinda suck. Apparently you can customize the templates if you go digging around for the menu template files within the installation directory.

Comment: Rats! According to this, one page menus are not possible (as of this summer) http://dvdflick.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=2705&p=12676

Answer (score 1):

[DVD Styler](http://www.dvdstyler.de/) will do the trick.

Comment: will this use filenames as menu items, one filename per menu item, without having to do any manual adjustment?

Comment: As long as you tick the use DVD menu option, DVD Styler is smart enough to use each individual file as individual chapters in a DVD.

Comment: to be clear, I'm interested in creating multiple titles (entries on the top level menu) not chapters (places within one title). Is this what you are saying?

Comment: Woots sorry, use "chapters" instead of titles. Yes DVDStyler will use titles, in short, individual VOB files for each video file you have.

Comment: Well, I tried this. I did not find a "DVD menu" option anywhere. Upon adding files w/ the file browser, a black square "menu" was automatically created. But the resultant ISO had just a black screen as a menu with no visible buttons or names.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pre-analyzed Linux solution reference,
[Scriptable DVD authoring solution for Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/23465/scriptable-dvd-authoring-solution-for-linux).

The basic idea is to use the [**dvdauthor**](http://dvdauthor.sourceforge.net/) tool from sourceforge
and wrap it up with any of the GUI front-ends.

Collecting the files together is done with a [XML file](http://nfs.shawnfumo.com/wiki/DVDAuthor/XML) based on an existing template.
Here is a [reference page for QDVD, describing this](http://qdvdauthor.sourceforge.net/templates/templates_howto.html) and
one more [sample reference at this LinuxQuestions thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/avi-to-dvd-358548/).

Some GUI options,

- [QDVDAuthor](http://qdvdauthor.sourceforge.net/) is a Linux Qt based solution
- [DVD Styler](http://www.dvdstyler.org/) is described in another answer here is available on Linux (wxWindows)
- [Polidori](http://polidori.sourceforge.net/) is a GTK based tool

Finally, there is a nice introduction on [Creating DVD videos on Linux and Unix](http://womble.decadent.org.uk/talks/dvd-ukuug06/dvd-talk-ukuug06-paper.html)
with a list of tools at the end.

Comment: Rolling your own XML file means inserting the filenames of the source files into it. This is what I'm trying to avoid. DVD Styler does this passably well (as another poster already mentioned). I don't know if QDVDAuthor and Polidori will do this (make default menus with filesnames as titles) out of the box. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: "Rolling your own XML file" can be done automatically with a simple script. If you use Linux, you're unfortunately expected to know how to write simple scripts.

Comment: The question states a gui solution is sought. And please don't make judgments of other people's coding abilities when you have no idea how good they are or why they're looking for a gui solution; that's not what this site is about.

Answer (score 0):

NeroVision Express might be a solution.
See this guide : ["VCD with Menu, Animated Thumbnails, video (image) background and chapters"](http://www.geocities.com/omegaweaponvcd/vcd_guide.htm).
NeroVision Express can be downloaded from [here](http://fileforum.betanews.com/detail/NeroVision-Express/1037929723/1).